# ImportError: dlopen(/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/PyQt5/QtWidgets.abi3.so, 2): Symbol not found: _InitSignatureStrings

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt5

I am trying to make work my python code on Mac OS Catalina 10.15 with Python 3.9
I get this error message when I run my code:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/alisa/Dropbox/cff/Python/Project/MyScript.py", line 139, in <module>
    from PyQt5 import QtWidgets, uic
ImportError: dlopen(/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/PyQt5/QtWidgets.abi3.so, 2): Symbol not found: _InitSignatureStrings
  Referenced from: /usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/PySide2/libpyside2.abi3.5.15.dylib
  Expected in: /usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/PySide2/libshiboken2.abi3.5.15.dylib
 in /usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/PySide2/libpyside2.abi3.5.15.dylib
```

Does anyone have any idea about how to fix this issue, please?

Comment: Recommendation: uninstall pyside2 as both libraries are in conflict for dependencies

Comment: Amazing!! :) Thank you so much